# Return two data frames in a function

Tags: r, dplyr

Is it possible to return two data frames in a function like this:

```
test <- function(){
  my.df <- data.frame(
    col1 = sample(c(1,2), 10, replace = TRUE),
    col2 = as.factor(sample(10)))
  other.df <- data.frame(
    col3 = letters[1:10],
    col4 = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10, replace = TRUE))
  return(my.df, other.df)
}
a,b=test()
```

Answer (score 1):

Return them in a list

```
return(list(my.df,other.df))
```